# Why is session for user_id, first_name when trying to retrieve it returning null?

Tags: python, session, flask

Here is my login code. When i try to retrieve it using sessions in another function in returns null. Why?

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    jsn = json.loads(request.data)
    res = spcall('login', (
        jsn['email'],
        jsn['password'],), True)
if 'Login successful' in str(res):
        session['logged_in'] = True
        session['user'] = get_userbyemail(jsn['email'])
        session['email'] = session['user'][0][0]
        session['user_id'] = session['user'][0][1]
        session['first_name'] = session['user'][0][2]
        session['is_admin'] = session['user'][0][7]
        session['is_customer'] = session['user'][0][8]

        recsuser = []
        for r in session['user']:
            recsuser.append({'email': str(r[0]), 'user_id': str(r[1]), 'first_name': str(r[2]), 'last_name': str(r[3]),
                            'address1': str(r[4]), 'address2': str(r[5]), 'mobile_no': str(r[6]),
                            'is_admin': str(r[7]), 'is_customer': str(r[8])})

        return jsonify({'status': 'Login successful', 'message': res[0][0], 'userinfo': recsuser, 'countuserinfo': len(recsuser), 'brands': recsbrand, 'countbrands': len(recsbrand), 'is_admin': session['is_admin'],
                'is_customer': session['is_customer'], 'email':session['email']})
```

When i to retrieve the values email, user_id, first_name, is_admin, is_customer it returns null.

Here is my code for retrieving the sessioned values.

```
@app.route('/car/platenumber/<string:car_plate_number>', methods=['GET'])
def get_carbyplatenumber(car_plate_number):
    res = spcall('get_carbyplatenumber', (car_plate_number,), )

    if 'Error' in str(res[0][0]):
        return jsonify({'status': 'Error', 'message': res[0][0]})

    recs = []
    for r in res:
        recs.append({'car_plate_number': str(r[0]), 'car_color': str(r[1]), 'car_brandname': str(r[2]), 'car_model': str(r[3]), 'car_rental_rate': str(r[4]),
            'car_image': str(r[5]), 'car_owner_id': r[6], 'car_category_name': str(r[7])})

    user = {'user_id': session.get('user_id'), 'first_name': session.get('first_name')}

    recsuser = []
    recsuser.append({'user':user})

    print recsuser            

    return jsonify({'status': 'Ok', 'entries': recs, 'count': len(recs), 'recsuser': user})
```

Comment: what is jsonify here ?Is it your custom function

Comment: jsonify returns the values of the objects @itzMEonTV

Comment: Can you confirm this code  branch `if 'Login successful' in str(res):` gets executed?

Comment: yes printed it in console and prints "Login successful' @OluwafemiSule

Comment: post your secret key config.Is that default ?It should be static

Comment: app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT' @itzMEonTV

Comment: Make sure to update your SECRET_KEY. See the subsection about [`How to generate good secret keys`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#sessions). I see that your response is JSON, am I right to assume you're writing an API service?

Comment: yes changed my secret key to random and still getting null values and yes this is an api service @OluwafemiSule

Comment: The cookie isn't sent by the client. You can explicit sign every client request with the cookie returned in the login response. However, I'll advice switching to token based authentication such as JWT & signing every request with a JWT token that can be used to reconstruct the user information. See [https://blog.risingstack.com/web-authentication-methods-explained/](https://blog.risingstack.com/web-authentication-methods-explained/)

Comment: You are doing this api call by browser, or using python itself ?

Comment: by python @itzMEonTV

Comment: Through python you need to manage session manually. Try using browser.